# How to redirect in Next.Js (CLIENT SIDE)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make a redirect if the user has a token saved in cookies or not, here's my code:

```
const Secret = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [token] = useState({
    token: cookies.get("token") || null,
  });
  if (token.token == null || token.token.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
    router.push("/login");
  } else {
    router.push("/");
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Secret</h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

But I get this error: No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.
Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem coming from where you put the code in. Your condition is supposed to be happened as the component is mounted, so try this:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
 if (token.token == null || token.token.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
    router.push("/login");
  } else {
    router.push("/");
  }
}, [])
```